# PowerShell - Fetch all the XML Nodes with based on an Attribute Value

Tags: xml, powershell, xmlnode, selectnodes, select-xml

I am trying to fetch all the XML nodes, where Attribute "Tag" value is "Fetch" with a XPath, without looping much using PowerShell 5.1. Please help.

```
[xml] $XMLValue=@'
  <Root>
     <Child>
        <Parameter Tag="Fetch"><![CDATA["Data"]]></Parameter>
        <Parameter Tag="DontFetch"><![CDATA["Data"]]></Parameter>
     </Child>
     <Child>
        <Test>
           <Node Tag="Fetch"><![CDATA["Data"]]></Node>
           <Node Tag="DontFetch"><![CDATA["Data"]]></Node>
        </Test>
     </Child>
     <Child>
     <Test>
        <Test1>
           <Node1 Tag="Fetch"><![CDATA["Data"]]></Node1>
           <Node2 Tag="DontFetch"><![CDATA["Data"]]></Node2>
        </Test1>
     </Test>     
    </Child>
   </Root>
'@
```

I tried to loop in each element of the XML using XML "SelectNodes" method and recursing, but it is too much to manage the depth. So is there an Xpath for this type if requirement, where I can filter the Nodes based on an Attribute value.

Output shoud be below 3 Nodes

```
<Parameter Tag="Fetch"><![CDATA["Data"]]></Parameter>
<Node Tag="Fetch"><![CDATA["Data"]]></Node>
<Node1 Tag="Fetch"><![CDATA["Data"]]></Node1>
```

Comment: The XML is not valid. Please edit the question and add correct sample data. If you have tried any XPath statements, add those (and the code using XPaths) and explain what they should fetch and what's the actual output.

Comment: Also, you must have tried something. Describe your attempt and where it failed. Otherwise it would feel you are just here to grab code you can copy, and you're not really doing that, right?

Comment: I could have added the Code here, but it is not working for me and little bit lenghty and I am looking for a Simple Xpath if it is even there.

Comment: "Selecting nodes that have a certain attribute value" is XPath 101. It's maybe the second thing any XPath tutorial teaches you.

Comment: Yes I am well aware of that. So tried with Command  : $XMLValue.SelectNodes("//Parameter[@Tag='Fetch']") and it fetches only one Node.
Is there a way to fetch all the Nodes where the 'Tag' Attribute value is 'Fetch' irrespective of the Node Name (Parameter/Node/Node1)

Comment: Ok I found it :)

Comment: Ahhh, **that's** the command and unexpected outcome that should have been part of the question from the start. If you have tried something promising and it does not do what you would expect, that's where things become interesting. - What was the reason, BTW?